# Simple unit test for Apache Camel SNMP route

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, apache-camel, mockito

I'm having some trouble getting a working Camel Spring-Boot unit test written, that tests a simple SNMP route.  Here is what I have so far:

**SnmpRoute.kt**

```
open class SnmpRoute(private val snmpProperties: SnmpProperties, private val repository: IPduEventRepository) : RouteBuilder() {

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure() {

        logger.debug("Initialising with properties [{}]", snmpProperties)

        from("snmp:0.0.0.0:1161?protocol=udp&type=TRAP")
                .process { exchange ->
                    // do stuff
                }
                .bean(repository, "save")
    }
}
```

**SnmpRouteTest.kt**

```
@CamelSpringBootTest
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
open class SnmpRouteTest : CamelTestSupport() {

    object SnmpConstants {
        const val SNMP_TRAP = "<snmp><entry><oid>...datadatadata...</oid><value>123456</value></entry></snmp>"
        const val MOCK_SNMP_ENDPOINT = "mock:snmp"
    }

    @Mock
    lateinit var snmpProperties: SnmpProperties

    @Mock
    lateinit var repository: IPduEventRepository

    @InjectMocks
    lateinit var snmpRoute: SnmpRoute

    @EndpointInject(SnmpConstants.MOCK_SNMP_ENDPOINT)
    lateinit var mock: MockEndpoint

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        initMocks(this)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun createRouteBuilder(): RouteBuilder {
        return snmpRoute
    }

    @Test
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun `Test SNMP endpoint`() {
        mock.expectedBodiesReceived(SnmpConstants.SNMP_TRAP)
        template.sendBody(SnmpConstants.MOCK_SNMP_ENDPOINT,
                          SnmpConstants.SNMP_TRAP)
        mock.assertIsSatisfied()

        verify(repository).save(PduEvent(1234, PDU.TRAP))
    }
}
```

However, when I run this test, it fails as the `repository` mock never has any interactions:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
repository.save(
    PduEvent(requestId=1234, type=-89)
);
-> at org.meanwhile.in.hell.camel.snmp.route.SnmpRouteTest.Test SNMP endpoint(SnmpRouteTest.kt:61)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Can someone help me understand why this isn't interacting correctly?  When run manually, this works and saves as expected.

Comment: Could you try adding a `mock.setAssertPeriod(1000)`, right before `mock.expectedBodiesReceived()` and see if it makes a difference? This is not a solution but just to check if it is a timing issue.

Comment: Thanks @ShellDragon, afraid it didn't make a difference :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I see what is going on here!
Your `RouteBuilder` under test has a `from("snmp")`. If you wish to deliver a mock message there for testing, you need to swap the `snmp:` component with something like a [`direct:`](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/direct-component.html) or [`seda:`](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/seda-component.html) component, during test execution.

Your current test is delivering a message to a Mock endpoint and verifying if it was received there. It does not interact with the real route builder. That's why your mock endpoint assertions do passed but `Mockito.verify()` failed.

**TL;DR**

Presuming that you are using Apache Camel 3.x, here is how to do it. I'm not fluent in Kotlin so, I'll show how to do that in Java.

```
AdviceWithRouteBuilder.adviceWith(context, "route-id", routeBuilder -> {
  routeBuilder.replaceFromWith("direct:snmp-from"); //Replaces the from part of the route `route-id` with a direct component
});
```

1. You need to modify your route builder code to assign an ID to the route (say, `route-id`)
2. Replace the SNMP component at the start of the route with a direct component
3. Deliver test messages to the `direct:` component instead of SNMP

**TL;DR ends.**

Full blown sample code below.

**PojoRepo.java**

```
@Component
public class PojoRepo {

    public void save(String body){
        System.out.println(body);
    }
}
```

**SNMPDummyRoute.java**

```
@Component
public class SNMPDummyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

    PojoRepo pojoRepo;
    public SNMPDummyRoute(PojoRepo pojoRepo) {
        this.pojoRepo = pojoRepo;
    }
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("snmp:0.0.0.0:1161?protocol=udp&type=TRAP")
                .id("snmp-route")
                .process(exchange -> {
                    exchange.getMessage().setBody(String.format("Saw message [%s]", exchange.getIn().getBody()));
                })
                .to("log:snmp-log")
                .bean(pojoRepo, "save");
    }
}
```

**SNMPDummyRoteTest.java**

Note: This class uses `CamelSpringBootRunner` instead of extending `CamelTestSupport`, but the core idea is same.

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@DisableJmx(false)
@MockEndpoints("log:*")
public class SNMPDummyRouteTest {

    @MockBean
    PojoRepo repo;

    @EndpointInject("mock:log:snmp-log")
    MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;

    @Produce
    ProducerTemplate testTemplate;

    @Autowired
    CamelContext camelContext;


    @Test
    public void testRoute() throws Exception {

        AdviceWithRouteBuilder.adviceWith(camelContext,"snmp-route",routeBuilder -> {
            routeBuilder.replaceFromWith("direct:snmp-from");
        });

        testTemplate.sendBody("direct:snmp-from","One");
        testTemplate.sendBody("direct:snmp-from","Two");

        mockEndpoint.expectedMinimumMessageCount(2);
        mockEndpoint.setAssertPeriod(2_000L);

        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        Mockito.verify(repo, Mockito.atLeast(2)).save(anyString());
    }

}
```

Logs from test run below. Take a closer look at the XML piece where the SNMP endpoint gets swapped in with a direct component.

```
2019-11-12 20:52:57.126  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.component.snmp.SnmpTrapConsumer    : Starting trap consumer on udp:0.0.0.0/1161
2019-11-12 20:52:58.363  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.component.snmp.SnmpTrapConsumer    : Started trap consumer on udp:0.0.0.0/1161 using udp protocol
2019-11-12 20:52:58.364  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootCamelContext      : Route: snmp-route started and consuming from: snmp://udp:0.0.0.0/1161
2019-11-12 20:52:58.368  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootCamelContext      : Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started
2019-11-12 20:52:58.370  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootCamelContext      : Apache Camel 3.0.0-M4 (CamelContext: MyCamel) started in 2.645 seconds
2019-11-12 20:52:59.670  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 10 seconds)
2019-11-12 20:52:59.680  INFO 32560 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.c.component.snmp.SnmpTrapConsumer    : Stopped trap consumer on udp:0.0.0.0/1161
2019-11-12 20:52:59.683  INFO 32560 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Route: snmp-route shutdown complete, was consuming from: snmp://udp:0.0.0.0/1161
2019-11-12 20:52:59.684  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
2019-11-12 20:52:59.687  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootCamelContext      : Route: snmp-route is stopped, was consuming from: snmp://udp:0.0.0.0/1161
2019-11-12 20:52:59.689  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootCamelContext      : Route: snmp-route is shutdown and removed, was consuming from: snmp://udp:0.0.0.0/1161
2019-11-12 20:52:59.691  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWithTasks   : AdviceWith replace input from [snmp:0.0.0.0:1161?protocol=udp&type=TRAP] --> [direct:snmp-from]
2019-11-12 20:52:59.692  INFO 32560 --- [           main] org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier    : AdviceWith route after: Route(snmp-route)[From[direct:snmp-from] -> [process[Processor@0x589dfa6f], To[log:snmp-log], Bean[org.foo.bar.POJORepo$MockitoMock$868728200]]]
2019-11-12 20:52:59.700  INFO 32560 --- [           main] org.apache.camel.reifier.RouteReifier    : Adviced route before/after as XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" customId="true" id="snmp-route">
    <from uri="snmp:0.0.0.0:1161?protocol=udp&amp;type=TRAP"/>
    <process id="process1"/>
    <to id="to1" uri="log:snmp-log"/>
    <bean id="bean1" method="save"/>
</route>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<route xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" customId="true" id="snmp-route">
    <from uri="direct:snmp-from"/>
    <process id="process1"/>
    <to id="to1" uri="log:snmp-log"/>
    <bean id="bean1" method="save"/>
</route>

2019-11-12 20:52:59.734  INFO 32560 --- [           main] .i.e.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy : Adviced endpoint [log://snmp-log] with mock endpoint [mock:log:snmp-log]
2019-11-12 20:52:59.755  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootCamelContext      : Route: snmp-route started and consuming from: direct://snmp-from
2019-11-12 20:52:59.834  INFO 32560 --- [           main] snmp-log                                 : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: Saw message [One]]
2019-11-12 20:52:59.899  INFO 32560 --- [           main] snmp-log                                 : Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: Saw message [Two]]
2019-11-12 20:52:59.900  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint    : Asserting: mock://log:snmp-log is satisfied
2019-11-12 20:53:01.903  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint    : Re-asserting: mock://log:snmp-log is satisfied after 2000 millis
2019-11-12 20:53:01.992  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.s.boot.SpringBootCamelContext      : Apache Camel 3.0.0-M4 (CamelContext: MyCamel) is shutting down
2019-11-12 20:53:01.993  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Starting to graceful shutdown 1 routes (timeout 10 seconds)
2019-11-12 20:53:01.996  INFO 32560 --- [ - ShutdownTask] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Route: snmp-route shutdown complete, was consuming from: direct://snmp-from
2019-11-12 20:53:01.996  INFO 32560 --- [           main] o.a.c.i.engine.DefaultShutdownStrategy   : Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 0 seconds
```

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, thank you!  This has sorted it for me now.