# Apache Camel Springboot test: Camel context is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm trying to write a simple plain spring test for Apache Camel. My goal is just to test if the Camel Context is started.

The code is:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
@BootstrapWith(CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class)
@ContextConfiguration()
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
class CamelPocApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext camelContext;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertEquals(ServiceStatus.Started, camelContext.getStatus());
    }

}
```

but the test fails because the Camel Context is null. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I finally had time to work on this project again.
The correct configuration is:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@SpringBootTest
class CamelPocApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext camelContext;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertEquals(ServiceStatus.Started, camelContext.getStatus());
    }

}
```

This way the test works.

Thank you guys! I refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802231/simple-unit-test-for-apache-camel-snmp-route/58826285#58826285) for more.

Now my questions are:

1. Why the Camel test [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/testing.html#Testing-SpringTestwithXMLConfigandDeclarativeConfigurationExample) states otherwise? Why isn't there the @SpringBootTest annotation and why bootstrapping with CamelTestContextBootstrapper.class makes the test failing either?
2. What is the difference between @RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
   and @RunWith(CamelSpringBootRunner.class)? I noticed the test would run the same.

Comment: Use @SpringBootTest and the annotations you need to use when testing with spring-boot. See the camel spring boot examples and their tests.

Comment: Claus is right. Additionally, I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58802231/simple-unit-test-for-apache-camel-snmp-route/58826285#58826285) a while back. You may find useful stuff there too.